# Maximum element order in $S_n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, permutations

Denote by $S_n$ the group of permutations of the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ with composition as binary operation. Let $m_n$ denote the maximum order that an element of $S_n$ can have. What is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{m_n}{n^k} < \infty$?

Comment: A simple OEIS check yields http://oeis.org/A000793, where also your question is answered as $lim_{n->\infty} (\log a(n)) / \sqrt{n \log n} = 1$.

Comment: From this post on Mathematics [Maximal order of an element in a symmetric group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/221211) we can learn that this is [Landau's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function).

Comment: This is Landau's function. There is no such $k$.

Comment: How strange! The question gets three downvotes while the (brief and correct) answer gets 10 upvotes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Landau proved in 1902 that the maximal order of an element in $S_n$ is $e^{(1+o(1))\sqrt{n\log n}}$. In particular, there is no integer $k$ with the property you ask for.